# copying portions of (date) data from one column and pasting into separate columns in Tidyverse

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I am trying to extract the year, month, and day from a single column (`"SightDate"`) and put them into their own respective columns (`"Year"`, `"Month"`, and `"Day"`) in a df. I used the lubridate bookdown (https://wrangle-r.rsquaredacademy.com/lubridate.html ch.9.8) to figure this out using the `year()`, `month()`, and `day()` functions, but it did not seem to work. I made sure the my `SightDate` column is a date data object and I still get 0 values for my year, month, and my new day column doesn't generate. I don't get an error, but a `tibble` output describing my df instead... I was wondering if someone can help me figure out why/what's missing in my code (below):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(hms)

HB_data %>% 
    mutate(Year = year(SightDate),
           Month = month(SightDate),
           Day = day(SightDate))
```

Here is some sample data:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  RecordID SightDate   Year Month
     <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
1    90064 2014-09-26     0     0
2    14333 2008-05-21     0     0
3   108894 2016-09-14  2016     9
4    19189 2009-09-29     0     0
5   118354 2017-09-23     0     0
6   117509 2017-07-04     0     0
```

And this is the data:

```
dput(SampleData, control = NULL)
list(c(38268, 115078, 96837, 34724, 118239, 120346, 49706, 95571, 
48824, 136498), c(14888, 17466, 16802, 14530, 17411, 17699, 15615, 
16711, 15568, 18060), c(0, 0, 0, 2009, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 
0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Comment: The `dput` shows a `list`

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your output for Year or Month based on the `tibble` showed

Comment: I'm having some issues with dput() when I don't specify control = NULL it produces an output that is so long that its not even contained in my console. I've also tried dput(droplevels(SampleData)) but that yields the same long output. I'm not sure why this is and hasn't happened to me before with longer sample datasets. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you use `dput(droplevels(head(SampleData)))`.  also droplevels is needed only when you have factor columns.  From the tibble it doesn't look that way

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working either my output is this repeated...```"'nonOM_Sightings1948-2019-138767.csv'", "'nonOM_Sightings1948-2019-138767.csv'", 
    "'nonOM_Sightings1948-2019-138767.csv'", "'nonOM_Sightings1948-2019-138767.csv'", ``` I've tried restarting my R session, quitting and reopening, but nothing is fixing it. I don't know why it's attaching the csv from which the data originates like this...

Comment: What is the `HB_data`?  Is it different from `SampleData`

Comment: It's the larger df that I used to generate the smaller SampleData df for SO questions. I'll try dput with that instead of the SampleData df...nevermind I get the same output as with the SampleData df

Comment: as I said, I couldn't get the output you showed.  May be you have loaded some packages that masked the `year`, `month` from the `lubridate` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227915/discussion-between-salma-abdel-raheem-and-akrun).

Comment: Hmm, I only have tidyverse, lubridate, and hms loaded and they shouldn't conflict owith one another but can look into this

Comment: As your 'SightDate' is `Date` class, I couldn't understand why you are getting zeros